# Take first n elements from System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

From a database I get the result as `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CustomObject>`. Putting the result into `List<CustomObject>` works flawlessly. Now I want to take the first n objects only. This is what I've tried:

```
List<CustomObject> tempList = DataBase.GetAllEntries().Cast<CustomObject>().ToList();
tempList = tempList.Take(5);
```

On the second line I get

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CustomObject>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CustomObject>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I also tried to add `OrderBy()`, use `ToList()` only (without cast) or a combination thereof, but everytime I get the error above. What should I change?

Comment: `tempList` is a list so you need to use `ToList` as `Take` returns `IEnumerable`.  Better yet just add it between the `Cast` and `ToList` on the first line instead.

Comment: @juharr: Thanks. Should I delete my question then or would you like to post an answer?

Comment: Declare tempList as IEnumeable<CustomObject>

Comment: If you only care about the first 5 ever put the Take(5) before the .ToList() then your list will only have 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `Take` *before* materialization (`ToList`):

```
List<CustomObject> tempList = DataBase.GetAllEntries()
  .Take(5)
  .Cast<CustomObject>()
  .ToList();
```

Let materialization be the *final* operation.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `tempList` is a `List<CustomObject>`, but `.Take()` returns an `IEnumerable<CustomObject>`. You can fix it simply by calling `.ToList()` again:

```
tempList = tempList.Take(5).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can add the `.Take()` method in your original query to avoid building 2 lists:

```
List<CustomObject> tempList = DataBase.GetAllEntries().Take(5).Cast<CustomObject>().ToList();
```

Comment: Why build two list? If replacing the var just inline the Task(5) before the tolist in the first line

Comment: @CharlesNRice I agree that would be better. I was just trying to address the question. I'll add the alternative to enhance the answer though.